# How to write in excel drop down list / combobox using uft?

Tags: excel, vbscript, hp-uft

I have to select / write something in an excel dropdown list (manually it is possible to select a value from the dropdownlist or to write it in the box).

[image]

I have the following code:

```
set objExcel = createobject("excel.application")
objExcel.Visible=True
set objWB = objExcel.workbooks.open ("<path>\name.xlsm", readonly=False)
set objsheet = objwb.worksheets("Project")
objwb.Worksheets("Project").Activate
```

I've tryied in several ways, including  objsheet.Cells(16,2) = "4162-P-0001",  without success

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I have to mention that the dropdown is done via a vba script

Comment: you need to show what errors you are getting.

Comment: I am not getting any error message. The test is passed, but the value isn't updated.

Comment: Take a look at [**`this`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/validation-object-excel) link. This will help you get started.

Comment: It worked like this: objsheet.Combobox1.Value = "My Selected Value"